# Find rows in a database with no time in a datetime column

Tags: sql, coldfusion

During testing I have failed to notice an incorrect date/time entry into the database on certain orders. Instead of entering the date and time I have only been entering the date. I was using the correct time stamp `createodbcdatetime(now())` however I was using `cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"` to enter it into the database.

I am lucky enough to have the order date/time correctly recorded, meaning I can use the time from the order date/time field.

My question being can I filter for all rows in the table with only dates entered. My data below;

Table Name: **tbl_orders**

```
uid_orders    dte_order_stamp
2000          02/07/2012 03:02:52
2001          03/07/2012 01:24:21
2002          03/07/2012 08:34:00
```

Table Name: **tbl_payments**

```
uid_payment  dte_pay_paydate      uid_pay_orderid
1234         02/07/2012 03:02:52  2000
1235         03/07/2012           2001
1236         03/07/2012           2002
```

I need to be able to select all payments with no time entered from tbl_payments, i can then loop around the results grabbing the time from my order table add it to the date from my payment table and update the field with the new date/time.

I can pretty much handle the re-inserting the date/time. It's just selecting the no time rows I'm not sure about?

Any help would be appreciated.

The following is the select statements for both orders and payments and if they need to be joined.(just fyi)

SQL Server 2008, Cold Fusion 9

```
  SELECT 
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders,
  dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp,
  dbo.tbl_payment.dte_pay_paydate,
  dbo.tbl_payment.uid_pay_orderid
  FROM
  dbo.tbl_orders
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_payment ON (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders = dbo.tbl_payment.uid_pay_orderid)


  SELECT 
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders,
  dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp
  FROM dbo.tbl_orders

SELECT 
  uid_paymentid,
  uid_pay_orderid,
  dte_pay_paydate,
FROM 
  dbo.tbl_payment
```

Comment: May I ask why you would want to store this information in two places?  Just on the surface, I guess I would question the data structure.

Comment: Hi mikeY
The reason it is in two places is that customers will be able to pay on account and the payment date/time will record the individual payments. However, I am lucky that the client has not started this yet, and therefore orders have been settled at the same time of ordering, hence why I can pull the order time for now. At a later date these will be almost for sure different dates and times.

Comment: Okay.  I see.  Just because the settlement dates in tbl_payments equal the order date now doesn't mean it always will.  And customer x could potentially have more than one payment in tbl_payments for order #2001.  Thanks for the explanation.  I was just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the records where the hours, minutes, seconds and millisecond value is zero.

```
select *
from table
where datePart(hour, datecolumn) = 0
and datePart(minute, datecolumn) = 0
and datePart(second, datecolumn) = 0
and datePart(millisecond, datecolumn) = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

You can probably get those values by [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) and checking for 0:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(datetimecolumn AS TIME) = '00:00'
```

That may not be particularly efficient though, depending on how smart SQL Server's indexes are.

Comment: Umm... when running this code I get time is incompatible with tinyint? The field is definitely set to datetime?

Comment: Hm might need to do `= '00:00'` instead of `= 0` or something like that. I don't have a copy of SQL Server to test with.

Comment: @JasonCongerton - I think Brendan's suggestion should work, though I cannot test it right now. If not, Jerad's suggestion works fine for me (once you drop the extra `=` sign).

Comment: You just beat me to it. I ran a quick test it on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and it works like a champ.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
....
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.tbl_payment.dte_pay_paydate, 101) AS DATETIME) = 
          dbo.tbl_payment.dte_pay_paydate
```

This will return all rows where the time is missing.

Comment: This works with the extra = removed (as per Leigh's suggestion) Thank you.